Laravel 9 how to load relations lazy on second level of the resultset
Our project utilizes the astrotomic/laravel-translatable library for translations in Laravel 9. We're encountering an issue where second-level relations (e.g., hasMany) that load their translations do not do so lazily, but instead make a request for each entity separately. This behavior generates a large number of SQL requests. Is there a solution to this problem? For instance, if the result appears as follows:
events: [
    {
        "xxx": "xxx",
        "translations": [  // This is lazy OK
            {...}
        ],
        "childEntity": {  // Second level
            "translations": [   // This translations are not lazy :(
                {...}
            ]
        }
    }
]


What's the code that generates this output? Also, since this is a 3rd party library (and/or if we can't figure this out), consider opening an issue on their github page: https://github.com/Astrotomic/laravel-translatable/issues

The solution is to add
$with = ['translations']

to all entities and now it is really lazy.
